# Layout similar to google chrome's tweetdeck app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-app

I am new to web programming. I want to use multiple column layout where each column will have content corresponding to column title, as used in tweetdeck app http://www.tweetdeck.com/ in my google chrome application. How can I go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox` to create the desired layout ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/WyuLk/1/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="container__column">Column 2</div>
    <div class="container__column">Column 3</div>
    <div class="container__column">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex; /* applying flexbox layout for all browsers */
}

.container__column {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1; /* 1 for equal column widths */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Are you asking how to achieve the same sort of layout or do you want to know how to populate a column with content?

If it's the former, you could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="columns" id="div1"></div>
<div class="columns" id="div3"></div>
<div class="columns" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#container {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.columns {
    width:280px;
    height:250px;
    background:#CCCCCC;
}
#div1 {
    float:left;
}
#div2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#div3 {
    float:right;
}
```

To give each column content it really depends what you're doing. If it's your own content, you could use a database and AJAX to pull in content from PHP scrips.